# OpenGL Additive blending causes white screen

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on a deferred shading project and I've got a problem with blending all the lights into the final render.

Basically I'm just looping over each light and then rendering the fullscreen quad with my shader that does lighting calculations but the final result is just a pure white screen. If I disable blending, I can see the scene fine but it will be lit by one light.

```
void Render()
{
    FirstPass();
    SecondPass();
}

void FirstPass()
{
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    renderTarget->BindFrameBuffer();
    gbufferShader->Bind();

    glViewport(0, 0, renderTarget->Width(), renderTarget->Height());
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < meshes.size(); ++i)
    {
        // set uniforms and render mesh
    }
    renderTarget->UnbindFrameBuffer();
}
```

EDIT: I'm not rendering light volumes/geometry, i'm just calculating final pixel colours based on the lights (point/spot/directional).

```
void SecondPass()
{
    glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE);

    renderTarget->BindTextures();

    pointLightShader->Bind();

    glViewport(0, 0, renderTarget->Width(), renderTarget->Height());
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    for (int i = 0; i < lights.size(); ++i)
    {
        // set uniforms
        // shader does lighting calculations 
        screenQuad->Render();
    }
    renderTarget->UnbindTextures();
}
```

I can't imagine there being anything special to do in the shader other than output a vec4 for the final frag colour each time?

This is the main part of the pointLight fragment shader:

```
out vec4 FragColour;

void main() 
{
    vec4 posData = texture(positionTexture, TexCoord);
    vec4 normData = texture(normalTexture, TexCoord);
    vec4 diffData = texture(diffuseTexture, TexCoord);

    vec3 pos = vec3(posData);
    vec3 norm = vec3(normData);
    vec3 diff = vec3(diffData);

    float a = posData.w;
    float b = normData.w;
    float c = diffData.w;

    FragColour = vec4(shadePixel(pos, norm, diff), 1.0);
}
```

But yeah, basically if I use this blend the whole screen is just white.

Comment: Have you output just the second pass to see if it's producing something that's all white? If you turn the intensity of the lights down lower, do you see the scene?

Comment: What are the pixels being written? What kind of image buffer are you rendering to? Are you using HDR and tone mapping, and if not, why do you think that additive blending without them makes any kind of sense?

Comment: Yes if I turn off blend I can see the scene fine (with only one light). I'll update my question with code on how i create my offscreen render targets.

Comment: I do not think you are clearing the color buffer for all of your attachments. I would need to see your `BindFrameBuffer (...)` function to say for certain.

Comment: @tempvar that's not what I asked. I didn't ask if you could see the scene with blending off. I asked if the second pass was producing something other than just white. It sounds like you're seeing the first pass, not the second pass when you turn off blending. My point was essentially the same as Nicol Bolas' point. If you're second pass is producing overbrights (or the additive combination of first and second pass are) then you'll see all white.

Comment: @user1118321 If I just call the second pass, the whole screen is black.

Comment: I don't understand how something visible additively blended with black gives you white. There must be some part I'm missing in the process. Sorry.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not actually rendering any light volumes, I'm only rendering my geometry to texture, then attempting to light that texture accumulatively.

Comment: I suspect `glEnable (GL_DEPTH)` in `FirstPass (...)` is part of your problem. That is a meaningless state to enable; you probably meant to use `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. You may also have intended `glDepthMask (GL_TRUE)`, I really cannot say.

Comment: I added glDepthMask(GL_TRUE) instead, and I disable it in the second pass. Didn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I fixed it, and I feel like an idiot now :)

My opengl was set to

```
glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

which (obviously) is pure white.

I just changed it to black background

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

And now I see everything fine. I guess it was additively blending with the white background, which obviously would be white.